# How to implement the Toolbar in the default Navigation Drawer Activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am using `Android Studio 1.0.1`. I created a new `Navigation Drawer Activity` that is by default provided by this IDE. It created 2 Java files -

- `HomePage.java`that extends `android.support.v7.app.AndroidBarActivity`
- `NavigationDrawerFragment` that extends `Fragment`

Along with that it provided me with 3 layout files -

- `activity_home_page.xml`
- `fragment_home_page.xml`
- `fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`

Now what I wanted to do was hide the Action Bar and instead get the Toolbar as I wanted to do some detailed designing. For that I took the following steps -

- Created a new style in `styles.xml`

  true
      false
- Changed the theme of the application in `AndroidManifest.xml`
  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`
- Created a `toolbar` layout and included it in `activity_home_page.xml`
- Added a Toolbar object to `HomePage.java`

  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

But unfortunately, my app force closes whenever I launch `HomePage` activity. Any suggestions?
[Logcat](http://pastebin.com/nvpMrmp2)

[activity_home_page.xml](http://pastebin.com/LZNsvvKg)

[HomePage.java](http://pastebin.com/QUF3vXc4)

[NavigationDrawerFragment.java](http://pastebin.com/PVgHMXuY)

[custom_toolbar.xml](http://pastebin.com/SnUu17bU)

Comment: `custom_toolbar.xml` please.

Comment: Added `custom_toolbar.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

In your fragment you have:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
...
toolbar.getContext()
```

However when you call `findViewById` the activity has not yet called `setContentView`. That means toolbar was not yet inflated and `toolbar` is set to `null`. Therefore `toolbar.getContext()` throws an NPE.

**Fix:**

Instead of `toolbar.getContext()` simply call `getActivity()`, to get the context.

---

If your fragment really does need the toolbar, you should call it after your activity's `onCreate`. A good place for that is `onActivityCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
}
```